# Cannot get Live Edit / Open in Browser (Chrome) to work in Webstorm 6

Tags: google-chrome, live, edit, webstorm

I'm very new to Webstorm 6, but I have searched extensively on how to fix this issue. I have Live Edit checked and the Chrome extension enabled. I believe my problem might have to do with how I setup the project. I made a new project from existing files that I was previously building with Notepad++. When I made the project in Webstorm, I designated the correct directory as the root.

When I try to use "Open in Browser," the file loads, but all of my links are broken. I have attached a screenshot, and as you can see, Webstorm is also failing to load my resources. What am I doing wrong? The same function works fine when I try it from NetBeans 7.

As you can see from the screenshot, the path for the index file is: file:///C:/Users/Dankoni/Desktop/Dev/Websites/Dankoni.com_Webstorm/index.html

However, if I get the path for one of my images, it comes out as: file:///C:/images/dankoni_ouroboros_default.jpg

I'm sure Webstorm doesn't have that much of an issue with relative paths, right? So, what has my noob ass done wrong? Will I run into this same problem if I remake the project and connect it to my site's ftp? Please help!

Thank you for taking the time to read this =)

I can't post images yet, as I don't have 10 rep points, so you can view it here: 
[image]

Comment: Please show how the image links are defined in your index.html file.

Comment: Resolved: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442648